# Theano learning AND gate

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano

I wrote a simple neural network to learn an AND gate. I'm trying to understand why my cost never decreases and the predictors are always 0.5:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

inputs = [[0,0], [1,1], [0,1], [1,0]]
outputs = [[0], [1], [0], [0]]

x = theano.shared(value=np.asarray(inputs), name='x')
y = theano.shared(value=np.asarray(outputs), name='y')

alpha = 0.1

w_array = np.asarray(np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(2, 1)), dtype=theano.config.floatX)
w = theano.shared(value=w_array, name='w', borrow=True)

output = T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(x, w))
cost = T.sum((y - output) ** 2)
updates = [(w, w - alpha * T.grad(cost, w))]

train = theano.function(inputs=[], outputs=[], updates=updates)
test = theano.function(inputs=[], outputs=[output])
calc_cost = theano.function(inputs=[], outputs=[cost])

for i in range(60000):
    if (i+1) % 10000 == 0:
        print(i+1)
        print(calc_cost())
    train()    

print(test())
```

The output is always the same:

```
10000
[array(1.0)]
20000
[array(1.0)]
30000
[array(1.0)]
40000
[array(1.0)]
50000
[array(1.0)]
60000
[array(1.0)]

[array([[ 0.5],
       [ 0.5],
       [ 0.5],
       [ 0.5]])]
```

It always seems to predict 0.5 regardless of the input because the cost is not deviating from 1 during learning

If I switch the outputs to `[[0], [1], [1], [1]]` for learning an OR gate, I get the correct predictions, and correctly decreasing cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is of form

```
<w, x>
```

thus it cannot build any separation which **does not cross the origin**. Such equation can only express lines going through point (0,0), and obviously line separating AND gate ((1, 1) from anything else) does not cross the origin. You have to add **bias** term, so your model is

```
<w, x> + b
```

Comment: so why does the same model work when changing the labels to learning an OR gate? I think that would also have a negatively sloped separator that doesn't cross the origin?

Comment: OR gate separator can cross the origin if you assume that being on the separator gives you correct "negative" value. It will not be the best one, but decent enough to use.